# Error(Uncaught TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i am using **react-router-dom v6** this code generating above ***error message*** ..please help me to solve the error ... ***backend*** is working fine ..i think this error is coming from fronted .... ***it works with postman***  ..
i am following a older tutorial ... now i installed new version of react-router-dom ... please help me out
this is ResetPassword.js file

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./ResetPassword.css";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { clearErrors, resetPassword } from "../../actions/userAction";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import LockOpenIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOpen";
import LockIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Lock";

const ResetPassword = ({ history, match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();

  const { error, success, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.forgotPassword
  );

  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

  const resetPasswordSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const myForm = new FormData();

    myForm.set("password", password);
    myForm.set("confirmPassword", confirmPassword);

    dispatch(resetPassword(match.params.token, myForm));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }

    if (success) {
      alert.success("Password Updated Successfully");

      history.push("/login");
    }
  }, [dispatch, error, alert, history, success]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <MetaData title="Change Password" />
          <div className="resetPasswordContainer">
            <div className="resetPasswordBox">
              <h2 className="resetPasswordHeading">Update Profile</h2>

              <form
                className="resetPasswordForm"
                onSubmit={resetPasswordSubmit}
              >
                <div>
                  <LockOpenIcon />
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="New Password"
                    required
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="loginPassword">
                  <LockIcon />
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Confirm Password"
                    required
                    value={confirmPassword}
                    onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <input
                  type="submit"
                  value="Update"
                  className="resetPasswordBtn"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ResetPassword;
```

And The backend code is here

```
export const resetPassword = (token, passwords) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST });

    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };

    const { data } = await axios.put(
      `/api/v1/password/reset/${token}`,
      passwords,
      config
    );

    dispatch({ type: RESET_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, payload: data.success });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: RESET_PASSWORD_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

**Thank you**

Comment: `match` is `undefined`. The issue is in the parent component that you didn't show

Comment: @KonradLinkowski question updated!!

Comment: I don't see how do you use `ResetPassword` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component API changed significantly. There are no longer any route props (*i.e. no `match` or `history` props*) all replaced by React hooks. The `history` object was replaced by a `navigate` function via the `useNavigate` hook, and route path params are accessible via the `useParams` hook.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ResetPassword = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- access navigate function
  const { token } = useParams(); // <-- access token path parameter

  ...

  const resetPasswordSubmit = (e) => {
    ...

    dispatch(resetPassword(token, myForm)); // <-- use token param here
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    ...

    if (success) {
      alert.success("Password Updated Successfully");

      navigate("/login"); // <-- call navigate here
    }
  }, [dispatch, error, alert, navigate, success]);
```